# How to structure my Class for XmlDeserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I'd like to deserialize a XDocument into a Class.

This is my XDocument:

```
<data>
  <request>
    <type>LatLon</type>
    <query>Lat 49.88 and Lon 8.65</query>
  </request>
  <current_condition>
    <observation_time>01:06 PM</observation_time>
    <temp_C>19</temp_C>
    <temp_F>65</temp_F>
    <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]></weatherDesc>
    <windspeedMiles>5</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>8</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirDegree>228</winddirDegree>
    <winddir16Point>SW</winddir16Point>
    <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    <humidity>61</humidity>
    <visibility>10</visibility>
    <pressure>1009</pressure>
    <cloudcover>20</cloudcover>
  </current_condition>
  <weather>
    <date>2014-10-15</date>
    <tempMaxC>19</tempMaxC>
    <tempMaxF>65</tempMaxF>
    <tempMinC>12</tempMinC>
    <tempMinF>54</tempMinF>
    <windspeedMiles>5</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>9</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirection>SW</winddirection>
    <winddir16Point>SW</winddir16Point>
    <winddirDegree>228</winddirDegree>
    <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]></weatherDesc>
    <precipMM>1.8</precipMM>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <date>2014-10-16</date>
    <tempMaxC>17</tempMaxC>
    <tempMaxF>63</tempMaxF>
    <tempMinC>13</tempMinC>
    <tempMinF>56</tempMinF>
    <windspeedMiles>12</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>19</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirection>SW</winddirection>
    <winddir16Point>SW</winddir16Point>
    <winddirDegree>233</winddirDegree>
    <weatherCode>353</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Light rain shower]]></weatherDesc>
    <precipMM>4.5</precipMM>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <date>2014-10-17</date>
    <tempMaxC>17</tempMaxC>
    <tempMaxF>63</tempMaxF>
    <tempMinC>11</tempMinC>
    <tempMinF>51</tempMinF>
    <windspeedMiles>21</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>34</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirection>WNW</winddirection>
    <winddir16Point>WNW</winddir16Point>
    <winddirDegree>284</winddirDegree>
    <weatherCode>176</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Patchy rain nearby]]></weatherDesc>
    <precipMM>11.2</precipMM>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <date>2014-10-18</date>
    <tempMaxC>21</tempMaxC>
    <tempMaxF>69</tempMaxF>
    <tempMinC>12</tempMinC>
    <tempMinF>54</tempMinF>
    <windspeedMiles>5</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>8</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirection>SE</winddirection>
    <winddir16Point>SE</winddir16Point>
    <winddirDegree>141</winddirDegree>
    <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]></weatherDesc>
    <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <date>2014-10-19</date>
    <tempMaxC>23</tempMaxC>
    <tempMaxF>74</tempMaxF>
    <tempMinC>13</tempMinC>
    <tempMinF>56</tempMinF>
    <windspeedMiles>6</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>10</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirection>S</winddirection>
    <winddir16Point>S</winddir16Point>
    <winddirDegree>190</winddirDegree>
    <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]></weatherDesc>
    <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
  </weather>
</data>
```

This are my Classes:
My main class - namespace = ObjectClasses

```
[XmlRoot("data")]
public class WindCol
{
    [XmlElement("query")]
    public string requestLocation {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("observation_time")]
    public string time { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("temp_C")]
    public string temp { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("weatherDesc")]
    public string weatherDesc { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("windspeedKmph")]
    public string windspeed { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("winddirDegree")]
    public string windDegree { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("winddir16Point")]
    public string windDir { get; set;}

    [XmlElement("precipMM")]
    public string precipMM { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("humidity")]
    public string humidity { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("visibility")]
    public string visibility { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("pressure")]
    public string pressure { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cloudcover")]
    public string cloudcover { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("weather")]
    public List<WindDay> windDays{get;set;}
}
```

my sub class - namespace = ObjectClasses

```
[XmlRoot("data")]
public class WindDay
{
    [XmlElement("date")]
    public string day { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("temMaxC")]
    public string tempMax { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("temMinC")]
    public string tempMin { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("windspeedKmph")]
    public string windspeed { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("winddirection")]
    public string windDir { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("winddirDegree")]
    public string windDegree { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("weatherCode")]
    public string weatherCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("weatherDesc")]
    public string weatherDesc { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("precipMM")]
    public string precipMM { get; set; }
}
```

With this piece of code, i try to deserialize it:

```
public ObjectClasses.WindCol Start(XDocument xDoc)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectClasses.WindCol));
        return (ObjectClasses.WindCol)s.Deserialize(xDoc.CreateReader());
    }
```

Comment: Infer the schema with `XSD.exe`, the use `XSD.exe` to generate classes based on the generated schema. You can obviously tweak it to your liking, but it provides a good starting point.

Comment: In addition to leppie's method, if you use VS as your IDE, there is a `Edit -> Paste Special -> XML as classes`  option that you can use to generate the same as what `XSD.exe` will

Comment: xsd is not possible, since this is for windows-phone